# Using sails.js to find out online status of users in Android app

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, websocket, sails.js

I am developing an Android app that uses a Sails.js server to read and write data to a MongoDB database.

I need a method to tell whether a user is currently online or not on the app.
The definition of 'online' for my app is that the user either has logged in and has the app open on any page/activity within the last 5-10 minutes.

One method I have considered is every so often in the app running a method that updates a "lastOnline" field for the User on the server with the current timestamp, then to check whether a user is online, checking whether each user's lastOnline field is within X minutes.

Another method I have recently considered is webSockets. I am aware that Sails.js has built in Socket.io features, however I am unsure how I would be able to use them for this functionality.
The idea I had regarding sockets would involve, upon logging into the app, connect to the server using websockets. On the servers receipt of this connection, the server would change an "online" boolean field in the User model to true.
However the main question I have with this, is if the app were to close, or become inactive in the background for a few minutes, how would the server then change the online boolean to false;

Thanks for any help or advice you can offer!